# PHP+MySQL check the title and insert specified tags if empty

Tags: php, mysql, insert

My database has more than 1000 rows, and all "tags" fields are blank.
I need PHP script to insert listing of specified tags if they are empty.
First, listed specific tags.

> Example: Barack, Obama, Barack Obama, Title, Example, Bill, Gates,
>   Bill Gates, Pham Phuong

It will check row 1 to n, if field "tags" is blank, do: Check "title", if any strings matched to specific tags above then insert to its tags field, separated by comma (,)

Current database "mydata"

```
CREATE TABLE `post` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL, `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `story` text NOT NULL, `tags` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
INSERT INTO `post` (`id`, `title`, `story`, `tags`) 
VALUES  (1, 'Barack Obama Title 1', 'Story 1 content...', ''),
        (2, 'Example Title 2 ', 'Story 2 content...', ''),
        (3, 'Pham Phuong story ', 'Story 2 content...', ''),
        (1000, 'Bill Gates Example Title 2', 'Story n content...', '');
```

After run PHP script it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You're saying that you'll check first if the "tags" column is empty. If it's empty, you will insert. Am I right?

Comment: Yes Carl Jan, If it already has tags, do nothing

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what your problem is and/or what you're looking for but just so you know this isn't good db design.  You'd want to separate the tags into a separate table and create a join table, etc.

Comment: have you written any code for this? where you are getting error?

Comment: My site has lot of posts without tags.
Now I want PHP script to import tags to all posts
In php script has array of specified tags. Example: Barack, Obama, Barack Obama, Title, Example, Bill, Gates, Bill Gates, Pham Phuong
When run PHP script it will check row by row, If any string in the title matchs to above array, it will insert to tags field. I need that PHP script because I cannot write any lines :D

Comment: @ alaric: Because I use CMS DLE, It has lot of fields but I only show some sample fields.

Comment: @MissPhuong In that case I understand.  I assumed you may have had a mostly-working script which you were having some problem with.  StackOverflow isn't a code writing service so I don't think you'll have a lot of luck getting someone to provide you a completed working script.

Answer (score -1):

you have " double comma in several wird places remove all this should work